# Require.js and Parsley.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, parsley.js

I user `require.js` and I want to integrate `parsley.js`. I tried to do this in my `main.js` file:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        parsley: '../lib/parsley/parsley-2.0'
    },

    shim: {
        'parsley': {
            exports: 'parsley'
        }
    }
});
```

but how can I use it? I mean how can I load the parsley module in the `define` function and do the same as the following?

```
this.$("#signup-form").parsley('validate');
```

Thanks

Comment: The code above tells requirejs how to find the module and how to use it once it's been loaded, but it doesn't tell it to actually load the module.  You need to require the parsley module, either as a dependency of another module (in the define call) or as an inline call to the require() function.

Comment: @Waxen, yes I know that, I'd like to know how to load the module and so how to use it to make a call like that `this.$("#signup-form").parsley('validate');`

Comment: [Parsley requires jQuery](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-installation-basic), so you'll need to configure your `shim` section accordingly; have a look at the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) for details. This will hopefully get you going, the next step would be to search for one of the examples on how to load and use jQuery-style plugins with RequireJS.

Comment: @kryger, I tried to configure `shim` in many ways, but still I don't know how to properly load the `parsley` module. I thought that the `requirejs config` would have done the job for me and so I should have only need to do `$().parsley()` but it tells me that `$(...).parsley` is not a function so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

parsely docs say to use for data :

data-parsley-errors-container="#ref"

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#data-attrs

It worked for my checkbox